# Como funciona o sistema de votação e classificação por estrelas?

Tags: lógica, programação-funcional, classificação

Eu vejo a classificação dos aplicativos nas lojas da Microsoft e Google e não consigo entender a lógica de ambas, gostaria de fazer classificações por estrelas! Mas antes preciso entender a lógica de classificação.

**Microsoft - Overkill 3:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Google - Whatsapp Messenger:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da pra perceber que em ambas, **5 estrelas** tem mais que todas as outras, porém a classificação fica entre 4,... como chegaram a esse resultado?

Gostaria de saber:

- Como funciona, qual a lógica da classificação (*Não precisa necessariamente ser delas, mas acho que funciona da mesma forma todas, apenas não entendo*)?
- (Opcional) Como por isto em código? *Obs: a linguagem de programação não importa, mas preferencialmente em PHP*

> Acredito que a pergunta não esteja boa! Entendendo o que eu desejo saber, poderia me ajudar a melhorar a pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Voto negativo na pergunta sem nenhuma sugestão de melhoria não ajuda em nada. Ao meu ver a pergunta é válida e está esta bem escrita.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php--net-11541 Achei esse link massa, acho que pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você chega a este resultado calculando a média ponderada dos valores.

Exemplo:

Dados:

```
5 estrelas: 733 votos
4 estrelas: 187 votos
3 estrelas: 102 votos
2 estrelas: 45 votos
1 estrela: 100 votos
```

Calculando:

```
(5 * 733 + 4 * 187 + 3 * 102 + 2 * 45 + 1 * 100) / (733 + 187 + 102 + 45 + 100) = 4,2
```